# How to show a ListFragment like progress loader in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have a `ListFragment` and I am parsing `JSON` by `AsyncTask`. While the processing is working, `ListFragment` shows a loader by default like this.

[image]

But in other `Fragment`, I have a `ListView` (not a `ListFragment`) and I need to show the same loader while the background processing is running. I am able to show a `ProgressDialog`. But I want to show a loader like the above image. How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by following github.com/johnkil/Android-ProgressFragment project. Thnaks Nikola for your suggestion.